# Using geodesic deviation for freely falling particles when gravitational waves comes through

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, geodesics

Suppose we have a gravitational wave which gives us the following metric $$ds^2=-dt^2+(1+h_+\cos(\omega(t-z)))dx^2+(1-h_+\cos(\omega(t-z)))dy^2+dz^2$$
I want to calculate the time it takes for a lightbeam to go from particle A to particle B where the particles follow a geodesic. I know that the geodesic deviation equation gives us the solution for the seperation vector (see Carrol) $$S^1=(1+\frac{h_+}{2}e^{k_\sigma x^\sigma})S^1(0)$$ and $k_\sigma=(-\omega,0,0,\omega)$. We should of course take the real part of this if we want to know the separation. So suppose our particles are confined in the $xy$ plane and more precisely on the $x$ axis say and the gravitational wave is going in the $z$ direction. Then we should see the particles oscillate and this of course affects the time for the photon  to go from A to B. Say at time 0 the seperation is $L$. Then my naive brain tells me that the time taken must satisfy the equation $$\Delta t=L-\frac{L-\text{Re}(S^1(\Delta t))}{2}$$
because as the light goes from A to B, the particles come closer (or go further away) from each other, hence (using $c=1$) the distance covered is exactly given by the above equation. So $$\Delta t=L+\frac{h_+}{4}\cos(\omega(\Delta t-z))$$

I do have the feeling that I am wrong, because I am just using classical physics to calculate the time it takes. So is this wrong or correct? Thanks.

Comment: To determine time of flight you'll need to integrate along the path of the photon.  I think Carroll uses this as an exercise.

Comment: @PaulT. Could you give me the exact number of the exercise? Thanks!

Comment: @PaulT. If you integrate along the path of a photon, you should get zero, because it is a null curve. So why does it work?

Comment: Hint: light trajectories obey $g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^\mu\mathrm{d}x^\nu=0$, which can be rewritten as $$\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{g_{00}}\left[-g_{i0}\mathrm{d}x^i-\sqrt{(g_{i0}g_{j0}-g_{ij}g_{00})\mathrm{d}x^i\mathrm{d}x^j}\right]$$ This is what you need to integrate along the path.